# Mercurial installation issue

Tags: python, mercurial, solaris

We've installed mercurial 1.4.1 and python 2.6.2 on a solaris 8 box. Now some hg commands work as expected, others fail.

I was able to initialize a repository (`hg init`) and add a file (`hg add`) but the committing (`hg commit`) leads to an error message:

```
abort: could not import module found!
```

I need a hint where to look - I'm not a python expert, is this missing `found` module part of the python distribution or does it belong to mercurial? Any idea how to fix it?

**Edit**

Thanks for your comments - `hg debuginstall` runs fine, just reports one problem - I didn't set a username in any of the config files. Can't believe that this causes the actual problems...

**Edit**

`--traceback` was a good hint!!

Here's the last line (can't copy&paste):

```
ImportError: ld.so.1: hg: fatal: relocation error: 
 file:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so: 
 symbol inflateCopy: referenced symbol not found
```

The zlib.so library is present was installed with either the python or mercurial package.

Looks like I'm not the only one: [here's the same problem](http://markmail.org/message/ybeuybrblcdfs6qs) with python 2.5 on solaris 10

Comment: Maybe you should download the source and run the tests. The error they give you might help you to understand the problem.

Comment: can you run `hg debuginstall`?

Comment: can you paste the output with --traceback on the command line? A full traceback would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the zlib library for your system (`libz.so`).

Comment: I'm not working on that project anymore, and honestly, I don't even remember if we solved it. Could be that we really installed a `libz.so` for the old solaris. Take my 'accept' as a appreciation for revisiting this old question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings.

If it is pulling libz from an odd place you will need to fix it so that it is pulling from `/pkg/local/lib` first

I was seeing this:

```
ldd /pkg/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
        libz.so =>       /import/wgs/lib/libz.so
```

But now its working for me.